# Displaying foreign key data in GridView/DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, detailsview

I have two tables..

`Students`

- StudentID
- Name
- SchoolID

`School`

- SchoolID
- SchoolName.

This is my scenario, I have created a `DetailsView` on my page which displays X StudentID and its columns. When displaying the SchoolID (from Students table) column it will display the actual ID as its supposed to.

I would like to know how I can display the actual school name instead of the schoolID, what I did first was simply have a query inside the first query which displays the name of the school like...

```
SELECT StudentID, (SELECT SchoolName FROM Schools 
                WHERE Schools.SchoolID = Students.SchoolID) 
                FROM Students WHERE StudentID=1
```

Although this works this creates issues when trying to edit the record via `GridView`, it will not save the correct data in those fields.

In the edit step in `GridView` I'm able to bind the SchoolID key with SchoolName, however this will NOT work when having a query within a query.

So my question really is how can I display foreign key data within Visual Studio without changing the SQL command?

Comment: **Join Query** `select st.studentId,st.name,st.Schoolid,sh.SchoolName from students st join school sh on st.schoolID=sh.SchoolID`

Answer (score 1):

The solution previously was to edit the Select command (after the SQLDatasource was created) to perform a inner join on the table containing the meaningful field name.

**Check Here**

**1.[Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1478549.aspx)**

**2.[Link](http://asp.net.bigresource.com/Forms-Data-Controls-GridView-Bind-Field-Foreign-Key-039-s-Data-Record-HKgFtlZnW.html)**

Comment: So I've tried what Link 1 has said, I have created the GridView first with just foreign keys and then altered SELECT sql to have joins for those keys. The issue I'm now having though is with the edit gridview function, I'm unable to link the edit fields to the parameters for the update query. It wont list the parameters in the Parameter Editor and it wont work if I manually just enter the paramters into the code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with join query, example:

```
select students.StudentId,students.Name,students.SchoolID,school.SchoolName from students join school on students.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
```

And, for better understanding of "JOINS" here is useful link: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: So the JOIN query doesnt fix the issue, however it can be used as part of the solution that AnandKumar posted.